# Escaping spaces in a select result

Tags: mysql, select, escaping

I have the following select statement, for which the result is sent to a command line parameter:

```
"SELECT show.file \
 FROM show, schedule \
 WHERE channel = 1 AND start_time <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP()"
```

However, if the result returned has spaces in it, it will cause the command to fail. How can I escape out any spaces in the result? Note that this select statement will only ever return one result.

Comment: What is the command, and why do spaces in the result cause that command to fail?

Comment: You probably need to quote the command line parameter, not escape the output of the SELECT. Show how this is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT REPLACE(show.file, " ", "\ ")
FROM show, schedule
WHERE channel = 1 AND start_time <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
```

Should do the trick. If you have another escape character replace \ with the respective one.

See also
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/string-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

If Markus' solution didn't work, try using the 'xargs' command.

```
xargs YOUR_COMMAND YOUR_QUERY_RESULT_AS_PARAMETER
```

depending on the command you're gonna use, it may or may not work.